# JQuery Iterate Around DISTINCT classes on a page

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to iterate over every class defined on my html page once. I can get classnames back using Jquery, but I'm looking of way just to iterate over each individual classname once rather than for each time it appears on the page.

Comment: you do know that classes are almost always reused on multiple tags in pages right ??? That's kinda their thing. Otherwise, add an ID attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda odd to do this, but here ya go

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Page</title>  
   <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(function() {

           var classes = {};
           $("*[class]").each(function() {
               var cs = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s/g);
               for (var i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
                   if (!classes[cs[i]]) {
                       classes[cs[i]] = true;
                   }
               }
           });

           for (var prop in classes)
               alert(prop);
       });
</script>
</head>
   <body>

   <div class="single"></div>
   <div class="one two three"></div>
   <div class="one two three"></div>
   <div class="one two three four"></div>
   <div class="one two three five"></div>
   <div class="one two three six"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i was more meaning if you have class one defined 6 times on a page, selecting this and applying on operation based on the class (e.g. a border round element) but only doing this once as opposed to 6 times

Comment: then no, that's just how jQuery works. It selects DOM objects based on your query and does things to them ... in your case 6 elements would have something changed .. 1 at a time. You want to look into changing your style rules at runtime which is completely different. You want something like this http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html